# How do I make an array without using array_count_values()?

Tags: php

I have an array, `$arrayName = array(1,2,1,3,4,3,2,5);`. I want the result as:

```
Array (
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 2
       [3] => 2
       [4] => 1
       [5] => 1
)
```

Without using `array_count_values()`, what is the logic behind `array_count_values()`?

Comment: Sure thing, read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Any time someone asks how to achieve something without using the built-in functionality that does *that exact thing* without explaining why, it just sounds like you're asking us to do your homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method will only loop each value once compared to other methods posted here.
Instead of looping the full array I get unique values and count them with array_keys and count.

```
$arrayName = array(1,2,1,3,4,3,2,5); 
$values = array_unique($arrayName);
Foreach($values as $val){
    $count[$val] = count(array_keys($arrayName, $val));
}

Var_dump($count);
```

https://3v4l.org/EGGJq

In your example I think my method may actually be slower than looping the full array, but if this was a large array there may be a benefit of not looping the full array.

Comment: Running `array_keys` has to loop over the array anyway, and this way you're doing it several times instead of once. I'm not sure this is going to provide much of a performance benefit.

Comment: @iainn with a large enough array it is faster: https://3v4l.org/YmEvS vs https://3v4l.org/1L3Ps

Comment: Must say I'm a bit surprised by that. Good answer.

Comment: @iainn in fact looking at the microtime of array_count_values my code is "only" three times slower. https://3v4l.org/QSLTV I'm quite surprised about that. I thought there would be 10+ fold difference.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use array_count_values function. That counts frequency of values in an array.
See this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

However, If you don't want to use that function, you can do an ugly way of for loop.

```
$arrayName = array(1,2,1,3,4,3,2,5);

$resultArray = array();
foreach($arrayName as $value) {
    $resultArray[$value] = isset($resultArray[$value]) ? $resultArray[$value] + 1 : 1;
}

print_r($resultArray); // Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Counting frequencies of array elements]

Counting frequencies of array elements

Comment: Please post the code rather than this image.